# Dynamically draw an Image on a Canvas in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, image, dynamic

I am attempting to put together a small game engine, in Silverlight.

However, I am currently stuck on a rather lower level issue: The ability to draw images, in different positions.  I intend on doing this dynamically through code, as, from what I've seen, most everything in XAML tends to be something that is at least somewhat static.

I have changed the base 'grid' into a Canvas, instead, so that I could draw anywhere on it.  Perhaps this was a bad idea, though, I don't know.  Any or all advice would help.

```
        InitializeComponent();
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Generic URL here"));
        ((BitmapImage)(img.Source)).DownloadProgress += new System.EventHandler<DownloadProgressEventArgs>(TestEventHandler);

        Rect position = new Rect(new Point(25, 25), img.RenderSize);

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img);
        img.Arrange(position);
```

My original attempt, above, was to use the Arrange function, above, to 'move' the image to a new position.  However, I have no idea how this works, and when I did the above code, the image no longer displayed on screen.

An unrelated question: is it possible to store images with the Silverlight application, as to not have them loaded via URL?  I know it likely is, but what I really mean to ask, is how I would go about that?

Thank you all for any help.

-Stefan Zuefeldt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use Canvas insteads of Grid is a good idea. Canvas is better than Grid in case you want to change position of its children controls
- To move the image to a point p, you can do it by:

  - add the image to the canvas
  - call Canvas.SetLeft(img, p.X) and Canvas.SetTop(img, p.Y)

- If you want to add images to xap, you can easily add the images to project, and set build type of the images to "Content" (default is None or Resource, I'm not sure), and then using relative url: img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/tmp.jpg", UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 1):

Dependency property of the image should be set to locate the image on the canvas.

[Canvas.SetTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop.aspx), [Canvas.SetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx)

To second. Of course you images can be stored within the Silverlight application. But their build action should be set to Embeded Resource.

```
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyNameSpace;components/images/someimage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1):

XAML does not have to be static. If you combine your XAML with a data model and use data binding, then XAML can joy to use.

You can move items on a canvas, what you want is the dependency properties `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`

[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/04/14/silverlight-simple-animation.aspx) is a little tutorial about simple animation like you are describing. if you google for "silverlight game tutorial" you will find tons and tons of blogs, articles, and demos with source code.

as for you other unrelated question... you can embed the images with your application.
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/katriend/archive/2008/04/27/different-ways-for-loading-images-and-files-in-silverlight-2-applications.aspx) is a good source on most of the methods for accessing files and images

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on SL apps with basic UI for sometime. I can give you some hints based on my small experience.

> I have changed the base 'grid' into a Canvas, instead, so that I could
>   draw anywhere on it. Perhaps this was a bad idea, though, ...

I think it s the obvious choice. As for positioning stuff on canvas, from this ref [SL Layout - Absolute Layout](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/layout,-rendering,-and-panels/layout-on-the-screen-%28silverlight-quickstart%29)

> To create a layout based on absolute positioning, you must replace the
>   Grid with a Canvas. ... To position controls on a Canvas, you set the following attached properties on the control: Canvas.Left & Canvas.Top

---

> .. is it possible to store images with the Silverlight application, as
>   to not have them loaded via URL? I know it likely is, but what I
>   really mean to ask, is how I would go about that?

You can always keep your images and shapes in a dictionary or smth (hence in the memory) therefore [resizing the images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (when your download is complete, for example) can save you from excessive memory consumption.

These are some of the things that come to my mind. Good luck.